# Basic For Loop Javascript Not Triggering

Tags: javascript, for-loop

Creating a basic JavaScript to add 100, 15 times to equal out to 1500.  However, the code down below that I did is not triggering and only returning 0.  I'm pretty sure I'm over thinking this or having my variables be called incorrectly.

```js
var monthlyDeposit = 100; // Code will be tested with values: 100 and 130
var accountBalance = 0;
/* Your solution goes here */
for (c = accountBalance; c <= 15; c += monthlyDeposit) {
  console.log(c);
}
```

Comment: `c` starts at 0 and gets incremented by 100 each time, so only the first iteration (while `c` is below 15) runs...?

Comment: change `c <= 15` to `c <= 1500` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are starting with `Javascript`, then let the `c` variable handle the iterations and put the logic that increments the `accountBalance` inside the loop body. This will make more explicit that the loop executes `15` times.

```js
var monthlyDeposit = 100; // Code will be tested with values: 100 and 130
var accountBalance = 0;

/* Your solution goes here */
for (let c = 0; c < 15; c++)
{
   accountBalance += monthlyDeposit;
}

console.log("accountBalance is: " + accountBalance);
```

```css
.as-console {background-color:black !important; color:lime;}
.as-console-wrapper {max-height:100% !important; top:0;}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your code, you are adding the value of `monthlyDeposit` to `c`, So for the first iteration, the value of `c` will be 100 which is not satisfying  `c <= 15` this condition.

```
var monthlyDeposit = 100; // Code will be tested with values: 100 and 130
var accountBalance = 0;
/* Your solution goes here */
for (c = accountBalance; c <= 15; c += monthlyDeposit) { //value of c = 100
//It will never come inside as c (100) > 15.
  console.log(c);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var monthlyDeposit = 100; // Code will be tested with values: 100 and 130
var accountBalance = 0;
/* Your solution goes here */
for (c = accountBalance; c <= 15; c += monthlyDeposit) {
  console.log(c); //<- c is 0 after that it will become 100 which is not less than 15
}
```

Because after the first iteration the value of `c` is `100` which is not less than the `15` hence you are getting the value of `c` as 0

Answer (score 0):

You are adding 100 to c but the condition you are checking is <= 15. Your loop will run only once.

Make the condition as c <= 1500 and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Initally `c=0`.After first iteration `c = 100` which is greater than `15`.If you want to run this 15 times. You set condition `c <= 1500`

```js
var monthlyDeposit = 100; // Code will be tested with values: 100 and 130
var accountBalance = 0;
/* Your solution goes here */
for (c = accountBalance; c <= 1500; c += monthlyDeposit) {
  console.log(c);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var monthlyDeposit = 100; // Code will be tested with values: 100 and 130
var accountBalance = 0;
/* Your solution goes here */
for (let c=1; c<= 15; c++) {
  accountBalance+=monthlyDeposit;
}
 console.log("Account Balance:"+accountBalance);
```